# Selecting Value with Typeahead

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Once the typehead is loaded and the filter is applied, I'm not able to select the value from the list, I don't know if I'm missing something on the line followed:

```
<input id="carSelected" type="text" ng-model="carFilter" placeholder="Car"
    typeahead="car as car.Owner for car in carFilterController.GetCars()  | filter:Owner:$viewValue} | limitTo:10"
    typeahead-focus-first="true" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Add a jsfiddle please, too many points of failure (how the data is built, how do you implement the getCars function etc)

Comment: ok ;) I'm new in Angular and Bootrap I thought that was an easy thing, I'll do that

Comment: I had to upgrade ui.Bootstrap from 0.11.0 to 0.12.0, and the issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

I believe `typeahead-on-select` is what you are looking for.

Sample usage:

```
     <input type="text" ng-model="queriedUser"" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Users"
        typeahead = "user in users | filter:{name:$viewValue} | limitTo:5"
        typeahead-on-select="goToProfile(queriedUser);">
```